# Autofac. Simplifying decorator registration with delegate factories

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to avoid changes in decorator registration by using delegate factories([autofac doc](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html#the-payoff)).

The current way that I know push me to change decorator registration every time when I change decorator constructor dependencies. For instance, if I add a new dependency to `FooDecorator`, some `IXyz` then I have to change decorator registration by adding `c.Resolve<IXyz>()`. Have a look at `CurrentWayToRegisterDecorator` and `DesiredWayToRegisterDecorator`

```
[TestFixture]
internal sealed class AutofacRegistrationTests2 {


    interface IFoo {}

    interface IBar {}

    class Foo : IFoo {
    }

    class FooDecorator : IFoo {

        private IFoo _inner;
        private IBar _bar;

        public delegate IFoo Factory( IFoo inner );

        public FooDecorator( IFoo inner, IBar bar ) {
            _inner = inner;
            _bar = bar;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void CurrentWayToRegisterDecorator() {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
            .Named<IFoo>( "baseImpl" );
        // Notice if I add a new dependency to FooDecorator constuctor then I need change this registration
        builder.RegisterDecorator<IFoo>(
            ( c, inner ) => new FooDecorator( inner, c.Resolve<IBar>() ), 
            fromKey: "baseImpl" );

        var container = builder.Build();

        Assert.That( container.Resolve<IFoo>(), Is.TypeOf<FooDecorator>() );
    }

    [Test]
    public void DesiredWayToRegisterDecorator() {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
            .Named<IFoo>( "baseImpl" );
        builder.RegisterDecorator<IFoo>(
            // Test runner throw StackOverflowException here
            ( c, inner ) => c.Resolve<FooDecorator.Factory>().Invoke( inner ),
            fromKey: "baseImpl" );

        var container = builder.Build();

        Assert.That( container.Resolve<IFoo>(), Is.TypeOf<FooDecorator>() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I do. My `DesiredWayToRegisterDecorator` Test fails with `StackOverflowException`. I'd like to know how to fix that